# Large mongo update queue burst issue

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing some user analytics tracking with mongo.  I'm averaging about 200 updates a second to documents (around 400k) based on a users email address.  There are 3 shards split along email alphabetically.  It works pretty well except for the daily user state change scripts.  It bursts the requests to about 6k per second.

This causes a tail spin effect where it overloads the mongo queue and it never seems to catch up again.  Scripts fail, bosses get angry, etc.  They also won't allow the scripts to be throttled.  Since they are update operations and not insert they are not able to be submitted in bulk.  What I see for me options are.

1:) Finding a way to allocate a large queue to mongo so it can wait for low points and get the data updated

2:) Writing a custom throttling solution

3:) Finding a more efficient indexing strategy (currently just indexing the email address)

Pretty much anything is on the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What are your "daily user state change scripts" doing?

Comment: Adding a small object to an array on the document via $push.

Comment: not an answer, but consider "heating" your document before calling the update.  You can do this by calling a find on it to get it into ram before the update.  Also, consider randomly updating.  If you are updating in ascii order, you may be defeating the point of your shard cluster by forcing all updates one node at a time.  If you can randomly update, you will do a better job taking advantage of the shard cluster.  Lastly, in my no scientific testing, I get about 500 updates/shard/sec on commodity hardware. Obviously there are tons of vars there. You may need a bigger cluster

Comment: Can you share a sample document and state change update? Can you also share the indexes on this collection?